# Desktop To Command Line Toggle for Default Command Line Environment?

Tags: command-line-interface, fedora, desktop

[Fedora 30 Webserver] I am wanting to use MySQL Workbench and Wireshark (amongst other things) on my server, but neither of those two programs can be made to work on the command line; so what I am wondering is whether or not there is anything that I could install that would allow me to toggle back and forth between a pseudo-desktop environment and command-line in order to run them?

I have good reasons for prefering the command line, only a 14" screen on the webserver (laptop) and do not want to be using VNC or installing a full desktop environment on the web server laptop if at all avoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Either install a desktop environment or don't, pick one. For a server, it is traditional to not have a desktop. Less to secure, update, and run in RAM. Download packet traces somewhere else, and connect to SQL remotely.

Virtual machines and containers are common these days. You can manage the same no-GUI environment for dev (VM on laptop) test and production (VM in cloud).

Linux desktops with CLIs on emulated terminals or virtual consoles still exist, of course. Command line is just another GUI app to pull up. However, these tend to be management or personal boxes. Anything running a serious service is on a server.

Comment: Thanks, - I will stick with multiple machines, as I have at present. I am not keen on cloud-based solutions where my data is liable to be arbitrarily deleted, censored, and handed over on demand to whatever agency demands it or at the whim of the service provider and in line with recent EU or US legislation.